# How to get the content of the tool window in Pycharm?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, pycharm, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a plugin for Pycharm (2019.3.3) and I want to get the running result that appears in the Tool Window.[It is the part in the red box in the picture--I want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WnZK.png)

Comment: Please check similar issue on dedicated forum: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000096950-Get-current-console-output-to-work-with

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but after reading the article in the link, I still don't understand (the code in the article doesn't suit the specific situation), so is there anything else.

Comment: You may check forum for similar discussions or open new topic.

Comment: This is the first time for me to ask questions here. Thank you very much for your warm help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am writing a plug for PyCharm. My goal is that when the user of the plug presses the "Run" button in Pycharm, I can get the running result, whether the operation is successful or there is an error.